# iPhone 6 is running on iPhone 5 specifications from storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8

I designed storyboard for iPhone 5,6 and 7 but the irony is that when I run it on simulator all works good. But when I run it on device, iPhone 6 is showing iPhone SE design not iPhone 7 (which is for 6 also).

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if **Zoomed Mode** is turned on and if yes, **disable it**.

Zoomed Mode causes an iPhone with a 4,7 inch screen behave like a 4-inch iPhone. Also, 5,5 inch iPhones behave like a 4,7 inch iPhone if the mode is turned on.

[Learn more about Zoomed Mode here.](http://1wayswim.com/blog/2014/9/27/iphone-6-zoom-mode-or-standard)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but if some client is using zoom options then how can we adjust our app with the respected dimensions ?

Comment: @QasimAliKhan With Auto Layout and proper size classes, the adjusting should work automatically.